# Iterating Through MongoDB Collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm working on a NodeJS application using a MongoDB database. I have a current ID of a document in a collection, and want to iterate through the collection starting from that id.

I have tried doing:

```
results = models.Book.find({_id: ObjectId("whatever_the_id_is")})
results.next()
```

However, that returns that results.next() is not a function. How can I iterate through the collection?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you do a find by _id, it will only return one record, not a record set, which is why `.next()` won't work

Comment: How would I start from a certain ID and then iterate to the next "model" from there.

Comment: I'm not sure of your use case. Presumably  you don't want all the records in the collection, so you would want some kind of search criteria, and also sort the data in some way (even if it's just by creation time/date). You could iterate over the records until you hit the desired id, and then start doing what you want?

Comment: Basically, I want to start from some point in a collection and then go on to the next model from there. I want to "remember" the location that it go from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can control the _id. Instead, Create your own key which will act like a counter.